# Can I upgrade ubuntu in preinstalled dell laptop

Tags: update-manager, preinstallation

If I purchase a ubuntu 14.04LTS **preinstalled** dell laptop then "can I upgrade ubuntu, whenever ubuntu's new version releases (i.e., ubuntu 15.xxLTS or later), via update manager using internet?

Comment: FYI there won't be another LTS until at least 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You can even install lUbuntu, xUbuntu or any other operating system (not excluded to Ubuntu flavors) if you want. You can even create a multi-boot with more than 1 operating system.

For that matter you can even insert a new harddisk with another pre-install of Ubuntu and use that.

There are NO restrictions. The only restriction you have is that you need to pay for some operating systems to make it legal to install. Ubuntu is not one of those ;)

Comment: So legally I'm allowed to, but practically, will it work or am I going to get lots of issues that means I'm better of starting from scratch?